# How can I parse path parameters from a url in KQL (Kusto for Log Analytics)?

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql, telemetry, azure-log-analytics-workspace

An application insights instance is tracking the request ingestion for a service with the following url path pattern:

```
http://testurl.net/item/{itemId}/store/{storeId}/buyme
```

When I go to log analytics to query based on the `itemId` and `storeId`, I can only see them in the url.  Since they aren't query parameters, the `parse_urlquery` function doesn't return the desired values.  They also don't appear in the customDimensions section of the query.  I'm starting to think I'll need to add additional telemetry just to be able to access these values in log analytics.

How can I get the `itemId` and `storeId` from the url (or any other field) in KQL?

Sample URLs:

```
http://testurl.net/item/123/store/5267/buyme
http://testurl.net/item/554/store/446/buyme
```

Comment: Please share some sample URLs

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz Does this address your request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
datatable(url:string)
[
    "http://testurl.net/item/123/store/5267/buyme"
   ,"http://testurl.net/item/554/store/446/buyme"
]
| parse url with * "//testurl.net/item/" itemId:int "/store/" storeId:int *
```

| url | itemId | storeId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| http://testurl.net/item/123/store/5267/buyme | 123 | 5267 |
| http://testurl.net/item/554/store/446/buyme | 554 | 446 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA0tJLAHCpJxUjdKiHKvikqLMvHRNXq5oXi4FIFDKKCkpsNLXL0ktLgHK6%20WlluhnlqTm6hsaGesXl%20QXpeqbGpmZ6yeVVuamKoH16ODUY2pqAtVjYmIG1xLLy1WjUJBYVJyqAFStUJ5ZkqGgpaCERb%20SAojyTLHKzCsBKoAYpaQApqGiWgDnsaN%20zwAAAA==)

Comment: That's so cool!  Thanks David!